# MD5 hash changes (6 bytes random change) each time Excel 2003 binary format is opened in Excel 2007

Tags: md5, excel-2003

I have a production problem where two MD5 hashes don't match between a server version of an Excel 2003 binary file (generated by Syncfusion .NET library) and a local one. 
When I upload a local Excel file that was only opened by double clicking via Windows Explorer the server finds that MD5 hashes are not the same and won't let file upload.
Just opening Excel 2003 file with Excel 2007 (and some reported the same with Excel 2003)
will cause a few bytes to change at the beginning of the file (I guess in Excel metadata at the beginning of the file)

To confirm that I used the file compare program from CMD console:

`fc.exe /b ExcelFile2003binary_Opened.xls ExcelFile2003binary.xls`

here is the difference between two files starting at offset 0000046C:

```
0000046C: D0 E0
0000046D: 61 51
0000046E: 5D 5E
0000046F: B6 FE
00000470: 76 0E
00000471: BB BC
```

Middle column shows 6 bytes of the opened file: D0615DB676BB and these will change each time the file is opened. The last column doesn't change since ExcelFile2003binary.xls is not opened.

Based on [[MS -OSHARED]Office Common Data Types and Objects Structure Specification document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/%5bMS-OSHARED%5d.pdf)
the affected bytes are at offset 0000046C (2 bytes) and at 0000046E (4 bytes) that change upon every opening of the file which obviously changes MD5 hash.

LinkElement-3 Example
This is an example of a linkElement that illustrates a hyperlink to a web resource outside of the document that contains the link.

```
Offset      Size     Structure                     Value
------------------------------------------------------------
0000046A    006C     VtHyperlink - linkElement-3
0000046A    0008     TypedPropertyValue - dwHash   
0000046A    0002     WORD - wType                  0x0003
0000046C    0002     WORD - padding                0x0000
0000046E    0004     DWORD - value                 0x00320064
```

If I understand it well "padding" and "value" change always. 
I heard from another thread that Excel 2007 doesn't change Excel 2007 binary format at all.

Please help. It is an urgent issue I need to fix. Is there something I can set on Excel document (using Syncfusion or Excel API) that will prevent this behaviour?

Thanks,
Rad

Edit:

```
Dim xlsUri As Uri
xlsUri = New Uri("c:\temp\ExcelFile2003binary.xls")

If (IO.File.Exists(xlsUri.LocalPath)) Then
  Dim xlsNode As TreeNode = wip.getWipNode(tvwMain.Nodes, "Excel")
  If (xlsNode Is Nothing) Then
    'Opening excel file link Uri embeded in Tag won't change the file????
    'Users can choose any way to open it (Custom app or Windows Explorer shell)
    folderNode.Nodes.Add("excel", "Excel", 9, 9).Tag = xlsUri.LocalPath
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Can you try marking the file as readonly? Is there a reason you need to open the file locally before opening it?

Comment: Yes there is a reason to preview changes. I need to check if I can make it R/O. That file is generated by an application using Syncfusion .NET library. Interestingly when Excel file is opened using a User control (inside a VB.NET Winforms application) by double clicking on a treeview node (see code above I added) it will open the file using Excel 2007 (I guess it usess association of .xls and the file that will open that extension) and not change bytes. It seems when .xls is opened using Windows Explorer shell than Excel 2007 behaves differently. I simply don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this has something to do with the metadata, but this only happens on excel 2003 files(no problem for word files, etc.).

And I found a way to solve this.

1. Open the excel 2003 (.xls) file
2. Click the office button on upper left corner
3. Choose Prepare -> Inspect Document. Inspect
4. Remove all the Document Properties and Personal Information.

Then after you save and close the file, the MD5 hash won't change when you just simply open and close the file.